# Applying a override to the validation in MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a validation class (as shown below)

```
private bool IsValidCustom(CIv2_AnnualLeave_AL civ2_annualLeave_al)
{
  bool result = true;

if (civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_EndDate < civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_StartDate)
{
  ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date";
  result = false;
}
if (civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_EndDate.Year != civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_StartDate.Year)
{
 ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Start Date and End Date should be of same year, please book seperate booking for different year.";
result = false;
}
if ((civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_StartDate.Year.Equals(Vie wBag.varCurrentYear)) && (civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_DaysRequested > ViewBag.varCurrentYearRemaining))
{
   ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Days Requested cannot be greater than " + ViewBag.varCurrentYearRemaining + " for " + ViewBag.varCurrentYear;
 result = false;
 }

if ((civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_StartDate.Year.Equals(Vie wBag.varNextYear)) && (civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_DaysRequested > ViewBag.varNextYearRemaining))
{
  ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Days Requested cannot be greater than " + ViewBag.varNextYearRemaining + " for " + ViewBag.varNextYear;
 result = false;
}
return result;
```

}

I need to write some code to allow if a tickbox is ticked to override the 3rd and 4th step for this validation but im stuck on how to approve this. The Tickbox coulmn is civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_IsUnpaid.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before rule 3, if the checkbox is ticked you return true and skip the other two tests

```
if(civ2_annualLeave_al.AL_IsUnpaid == true){
    return true;
}
```